# Java SimpleDatetime parse

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

Maybe i'm just missing the obvious, but I can't get `SimpleDateTime`s `parse()` method to work:

I want to parse dates like `June 19, 2011`. So, according to the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

for my needs it should be:

- `M`:  Month in year.  If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; --> `MMM`
- `d`: Day in month.  For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields --> `d`
- `y`: Year. For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. --> `yyyy`

but with

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse("June 19, 2011");
```

I'll always get `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "June 19, 2011"`

Where am I thinking wrong? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your `Locale` is some German value since you seem to be in Germany. `June` won't parse as a German word for a month. Set your `Locale` to an English value.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: I recommend always specifying both **time zone** and **locale** to avoid these kinds of problems with implicit defaults.

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Here is an example akin to [the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26076637/642706) but using the Joda-Time library.

Both Joda-Time and the java.time package are far superior to the old java.util.Date an .Calendar classes bundled with Java. One of many advantages is a class, `LocalDate`, to represent date-only values without time-of-day or time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MMM, d, YYYY" ).withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH );
LocalDate localDate = formatter.parseLocalDate( "June 19, 2011" );
```